# Strange Date returned from laravel

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, datetime

I am posting a date to my database. The column type is TIMESTAMP but no matter what I send, laravel isn't converting the dates. I've manually checked that Carbon::parse() can format the date that I am sending correctly and that's fine.

Posted date example: `{ "interview_date": "18 December 2015 - 14:24" }`

Saves in Database as: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Returned as: `{ "interview_date": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00" }`

I have set `protected $dates = ['interview_date'];` in my laravel model.

What is happening to my date? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Joe

UPDATE: Model / Controller / Laravel 5.1

```
<?php

namespace App\Clients;

use AlgoliaSearch\Laravel\AlgoliaEloquentTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
use AlgoliaEloquentTrait;

public $primaryKey = "m_id";

protected $dates = ['interview_date'];

public $timestamps = false;

public static $objectIdKey = 'member_lead_trace';

public $indices = ['dev_leads'];

 protected $casts = [
    'interview_notes_received' => 'boolean',
    'interview_complete' => 'boolean',
];

public function leads()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Lead', 'id', 'member_lead_trace');
}

public function personal()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Personal', 'mem_id', 'm_id');
}

public function wants()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Want', 'mem_id', 'm_id');
}

public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Photo', 'mem_id', 'm_id');
}

public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute', 'mem_id', 'm_id');
}

public function financial()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Financial', 'mem_id', 'm_id');
}

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'mem_id', 'm_id');
}
}
```

Controller function

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->data, true);

    //return Carbon::parse($request->interview_date);


    try {
        return Member::where('member_lead_trace', $request->user)->update($data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Running Carbon with tinker the parse method doesn't seem to work for the time your showing in your example

```
Carbon::parse('18 December 2015 - 14:24');
```

> Exception with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (18 December 2015 - 14:24) at position 17 (-): Unexpected character'

However removing the - it parses correctly

```
Carbon::parse('18 December 2015 14:24');
```

A valid Carbon instance is returned

```
Carbon\Carbon {#673   +"date": "2015-12-18 14:24:00.000000"  
+"timezone_type": 3   +"timezone": "UTC" }
```

An alternative to removing the - is to specify the format which can be done like so

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - G:i', '18 December 2015 - 14:24');
```

This is assuming you have leading zeros on the day and the hour see the [format options](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) if thats not the case.

UPDATE:

After looking at your code and looking at what Laravel has been doing I think we've been working under the false assumption that Laravel will just figure out the date format automatically. I'm happy to be proven wrong on this.

However the solution I've come up with that seems to work is to do

```
public function setInterviewDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['interview_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $value)->toDateString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Thats strange as it seems to be parsing OK for me before it hits the database, but I can remove it. However it seems the protected dates isn't being looked at? I can only get the model to save if I send the date in exactly the right format for mySQL?

Comment: This is my save line `Member::where('member_lead_trace', $request->user)->update( $data )`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Could you update your question with your full model and maybe your migration for the table. Definitely seems something funny going on.

Comment: If your using Laravel 4 then you need to specify the date mutator in a different way see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators

Comment: Thanks Mark, it's 5.1... I've added the model etc

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Strangely enough, if I change to the `$model->save()` way of saving the model, it seems to hit that dates property. I get an `InvalidArgumentException - The separation symbol could not be found`   .

Answer (score 0):

Default format of date in mysql is, `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`.

You have to sore in that format only.

So before inserting the data, convert date like this,

```
$d = "date in other format";
$date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s,strtotime($d));
```

Comment: If he's passing in an instance of Carbon Laravel should handle it no problem. So this shouldn't be required.